# Add class to active links in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP `link` to generate anchor tags. Now i want to add a class to active links to apply some styling to those links.

Is there a way to that?

Comment: How do you define "active link"?

Comment: Links of cuurent page is active link. I mean active anchor ( a:active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by setting a style using CSS, not exactly in CakePHP:

```
a.link_class:visited {}
a.link_class:active {}
a.link_class:hover {}
```

And defining a class to your link:

```
echo $this->Html->link('your link', array(...), array('class' => 'link_class'));
```

I hope it helps.